# rhomobile - rhostudio where does it store the data?

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

i just finished watching this best [video](http://vimeo.com/31755872) and in this video it shows how to create a simple project (products) and the video was very clear and to the point but what i dont understand is that where does it storing the data? and how do i check the data if i want to see? does it crate tables too?
i am totaly lost after this video and not sure how does the app interecting with the db

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default, data is stored in a single table. It uses a property bag method to store. You can already use a fixed schema, where you create your own tables, indexes...
In a property bag approach, all your data is stored in a table called object_values.
If property bag schema is used, there are two important tables:
- SOURCES: It stores your model definitions.
- OBJECT_VALUES: Here is where all your data is stored.

If you are using the simulator, search for a sqlite database called syncdblocal.sqlite.

All information is here: http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/rhom

Comment: how does it work when i deploy the app to the martket? sholuld i also endup deploying the tables etc???